# Why doesn't Google use GWT in most of its applications?

Tags: web-development, web-applications, google, gwt

Google created [Google Web Toolkit (GWT)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Web_Toolkit) and doesn't use it when building their own web applications.

Does this mean GWT is not suitable for building dynamic applications? Or have caching problems? Or have RPC problems? Or are there other concerns that prevent Google from using this technology?

`EDIT`: I don't say here that Google don't ever used GWT in any app, but What I am want to say, why they are not using it in a wide range?

Comment: GMail isn't dynamic enough? They use it where it's appropriate.

Comment: GWT is still a very young project and isn't yet ready for prime time.

Comment: Google wave was written using GWT. http://www.google.com/events/io/2009/sessions/GoogleWavePoweredByGWT.html

Comment: Google uses GWT in numerous products. See https://plus.sandbox.google.com/110412141990454266397/posts/ivVepvxCu3g.

Answer (score 17):

Well, firstly, most Google products are older than GWT. You don't re-write a perfectly good product every time a new library is released.

Secondly -- and this is really my personal opinion -- is that GWT is to Javascript what ASP.NET (classic) is to HTML. It's great for simple interfaces, but if you need to do anything complex, it can be a bit of a pain.

A lot of projects at Google are written using the [Closure Javascript library](http://code.google.com/closure/library/). Closure stays closer to the "metal" of the browser, while still providing powerful templating and many other features that a complex web application requires.

Having said that, there *are* projects within Google that use GWT. The AdWords frontend is one that comes to mind.

Answer (score 7):

What you are talking about is a concept commonly known as:

## [eat your own dog food](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eating_your_own_dog_food)

However, not all companies can really be their own customers. For example, consider Microsoft. SQL Server in previous versions were not as powerful as now for enterprise purposes. Thus Microsoft couldn't use it and it had to use something like Oracle, or DB2 for enterprise level developments.

I mean, the first point is that **not everybody should eat his/her own dog food**.

The second point is that, how can you ever get sure that Google is not using GWT? I mean, after all, what it produces is JavaScript and they can have it customized, so that it doesn't contain any kind of signature to denote the usage of GWT. In other words, almost any platform on the web can be configured such that no-one understand what language, OS, web server, etc. has been used to create it.

For example, sites built with ASP.NET and running on IIS have an HTTP Response header field known as `X-Powered-By: ASP.NET`, or something like that. But you can easily delete these headers from IIS. Also websites created by ASP.NET usually have paths ending with `.aspx` files. However, this also can be easily changed to extension-less URLs with the concept of URL Rewriting.

So the second point I'm emphasizing, is that, you can't ever for sure say that **Google is not using GWT**. Maybe it does.